# How to know a pixel is in a CvBlob?

Tags: c++, image-processing

I'm using CvBlob library, the CvBlob struct is below

```
 struct CvBlob
  {
    CvLabel label; ///< Label assigned to the blob.

    union
    {
      unsigned int area; ///< Area (moment 00).
      unsigned int m00; ///< Moment 00 (area).
    };

    unsigned int minx; ///< X min.
    unsigned int maxx; ///< X max.
    unsigned int miny; ///< Y min.
    unsigned int maxy; ///< y max.

    CvPoint2D64f centroid; ///< Centroid.

    double m10; ///< Moment 10.
    double m01; ///< Moment 01.
    double m11; ///< Moment 11.
    double m20; ///< Moment 20.
    double m02; ///< Moment 02.

    double u11; ///< Central moment 11.
    double u20; ///< Central moment 20.
    double u02; ///< Central moment 02.

    double n11; ///< Normalized central moment 11.
    double n20; ///< Normalized central moment 20.
    double n02; ///< Normalized central moment 02.

    double p1; ///< Hu moment 1.
    double p2; ///< Hu moment 2.

    CvContourChainCode contour;           ///< Contour.
    CvContoursChainCode internalContours; ///< Internal contours.
  };
```

I have two questions for this:

1. How to know a pixel with (x,y) coordinate is in a blob?
2. I don't understand the mean of all fields in this struct, someone can explain to me?

Many thanks!

T&T

Answer (score 1):

1- Never used cvblob, but [pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#pointpolygontest) is what you need, it seems.

Something like

```
pointPolygonTest(contour, Point2f(x,y), false);
```

should be used.

2- This struct seems like an interface to [shape descriptors](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#structural-analysis-and-shape-descriptors) used in opencv. Moments, area, hu moments, etc. are all wrapped. `Moments` are used to find center of mass (centroid), area, rotational invariance and for shape matching in general. `Contour` is the boundary of your blob. `Internal contours` are children contours that lie inside. `Max and min points` are the exterior points, which could help one define a bounding rectangle. `Label` seems to be just a sticker